# apache 2.4 LocationMatch not catching

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, locationmatch

I need to set htaccess directives in a virtual host for everything that isn't either / or /example/{anything}.  I've looked at everything I can find an it seems like apache is doing something weird with regex I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here is what I am trying, maybe someone can help me.

```
<Location "/">
  ...
</Location>
<LocationMatch "^(?!/example/.+)$">
 ...
</LocationMatch>
```

I'm stumped I've been trying different approaches all day.

Adding more to this the positive version of the regex works fine
so

```
<LocationMatch "^(/example/.+)$">
```

works as expected, just the negative version always fails.

Comment: Shouldn't you escape / character? like this: <LocationMatch "^(?!\/example\/.+)$">

Comment: @berkin Generally in regex, but LocationMatch doesn't seem to care about / at least according to other examples, but  I did try escaping it and I get the same result anyhow.

Comment: Simple `^/example/?` isn't working?

Comment: @emix Maybe I'm not clear on what you're saying but  that looks like will catch the presence of /example/{anything} but I want to catch anything that isn't /example/{anything}

Comment: How about `^(?!/example/?).+` ?

Comment: @mcoatney [test pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N3I0Aq/1/)

Comment: @emix It should work I think but for some reason this is applying the rule categorically including to /example/{anything}

Comment: @bobblebubble Same story unfortunately, I get the rule for everything, IDK what what is up with LocationMatch.